# Docker entrypoint script doesnt run all commands with compose

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose set-up with several containers.

I copy the following docker-entrypoint.sh file over:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$1" = "slurmdbd" ]
then
    echo "---> Starting the MUNGE Authentication service (munged) ..."
    gosu munge /usr/sbin/munged

    echo "---> Starting the Slurm Database Daemon (slurmdbd) ..."

    {
        . /etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf
        until echo "SELECT 1" | mysql -h $StorageHost -u$StorageUser -p$StoragePass 2>&1 > /dev/null
        do
            echo "-- Waiting for database to become active ..."
            sleep 2
        done
    }
    echo "-- Database is now active ..."
    
    exec gosu slurm /usr/sbin/slurmdbd -Dvvv
fi

if [ "$1" = "slurmctld" ]
then
    echo "---> Starting the MUNGE Authentication service (munged) ..."


    echo "---> Waiting for slurmdbd to become active before starting slurmctld ..."

    until 2>/dev/null >/dev/tcp/slurmdbd/6819
    do
       echo "-- slurmdbd is not available.  Sleeping ..."
        sleep 2
    done
    echo "-- slurmdbd is now active ..."

    echo "---> Starting the Slurm Controller Daemon (slurmctld) ..."

    

    exec /sbin/init
    gosu munge /usr/sbin/munged 
    exec gosu slurm /usr/sbin/slurmctld -Dvvv 
    
fi

if [ "$1" = "slurmd" ]
then
    echo "---> Starting the MUNGE Authentication service (munged) ..."
    gosu munge /usr/sbin/munged

    echo "---> Waiting for slurmctld to become active before starting slurmd..."

    until 2>/dev/null >/dev/tcp/slurmctld/6817
    do
        echo "-- slurmctld is not available.  Sleeping ..."
        sleep 2
    done
    echo "-- slurmctld is now active ..."

    echo "---> Starting the Slurm Node Daemon (slurmd) ..."
    exec /usr/sbin/slurmd -Dvvv
fi

exec "$@"
```

and have `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoin.sh"] in my Dockerfile.

When the command is "slurmctld" it should run the second part of that script containing the following:

```
gosu munge /usr/sbin/munged 
exec gosu slurm /usr/sbin/slurmctld -Dvvv
```

but it doesnt seem to. If I move those commands above the `exec /sbin/init` command they run.

I know they don't get run as other containers wait for them to run before running their party of the entrypoint script (the third part of  the script after the `until`).

If I leave the script as is and log in to the container and issue the commands:

```
gosu munge /usr/sbin/munged 
exec gosu slurm /usr/sbin/slurmctld -Dvvv
```

myself by hand they run fine, and the other dependent containers then run their part of the entrypoint script.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to get the commands to run after the `exec /sbin/init` command.

Thanks!

**Update**

with `set -ex` it gives the following:

```
slurmctld  | + echo '-- slurmdbd is now active ...'
slurmctld  | + echo '---> Starting the Slurm Controller Daemon (slurmctld) ...'
slurmctld  | + exec /sbin/init
slurmctld  | -- slurmdbd is now active ...
slurmctld  | ---> Starting the Slurm Controller Daemon (slurmctld) ...
```

Comment: If you set the `-x` flag in your script (`set -ex`) to enable tracing output, what do you see?

Comment: Updated with the output with `set -ex` nothing happens on tat container after that - though it is up fine, and I can log in and run the final commands no problem.

Comment: This seems like you're trying to build one container that runs a minimum of two services at a time, with which one controlled by the command parameter.  This isn't usually a best practice.  Can you split this into separate containers (possibly using the same image) for `munged`, `slurmdbd`, `slurmctld`, and `slurmd`; each only running that process as the main container command, without this entrypoint script at all?

Comment: To more directly answer your question, `exec something` replaces the shell script with the `something` process.  Assuming `something` exists and is executable, nothing will ever happen after a shell `exec` command like this.

Comment: Ah ok David Maze - thanks. Never used the exec command before this. Understand what is going on now.